# How to retrieve a systemctl service's notion of the "current time" (CRON jobs run two hours early)?

Tags: debian, shell, cron, time, systemctl

My scheduled CRON jobs run two hours early, although both `date` and `hwclock` reports the correct time for my timezone.

I've read that a possible [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/231220/why-are-cronjobs-running-at-the-wrong-time) would be to restart `cron.service` (CRON) after changing the time zone (I've **not** changed the time zone manually)

Is it possible to check the `cron.service`
's notion of the "current time" in order to verify, whether it needs to be restarted?

Comment: `0 * * * * date >/tmp/thetime.txt` maybe?